# GIT LFS lockable files not set as read-only

Tags: git, git-lfs

Hello I have the following issue. In a repository we have been using for quite a time, I have enabled GIT LFS locking on a certain binary file type. I am able to lock stuff using `git lfs lock` and also list all the locks by `git lfs locks`. However, I think that under normal circumstances all of the files with the lockable extension should be read-only. That's however not the case until I lock the file and unlock it again. But obviously, I am not going to do that for thousands of files. It looks like some sort of a bug. There should be some kind of operation that refreshes the read-only attribute for all of the lockable files. Is there something like that? Cause I haven't been able to find it.

It may have been caused by the fact, that I enabled the locking on a separate branch and then merged it to the main branch, but that's just a wild guess.

I believe that if this was a new repo and I would have added new files, it would have behaved well, but how do I do this correctly for a repo that already has a lot of files with the extension I am just about to make lockable?

Thanks for any ideas...

// This is Windows we're talking in case it matters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `git checkout .` should do the trick as described in here:
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3555

In my case, however, it was solved by moving the repo to another computer (not that I intended to do this as a solution, I was just migrating the data to a new computer) and running `git status` which seemed to refresh everything.